# ModSecurity WAF - Apache Wont Restart

Tags: apache-http-server, ubuntu

I installed the Mod_Security module on my VPS server the other day. I moved the *core rules* to the *activated rules* folder, which didn't cause an error. But, when I put the commands in my *mod-security.conf* file and restart apache, it wont start again until I remove the commands below.

If this is some help, there's a config file on my *modsecurity-crs* folder, but not in the *activated rules* folder. Did I miss something?

```
Include "/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/*.conf"
Include "/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/activated_rules/*.conf"
```

My VPS runs Ubuntu OS with an Apache web server.

This is the tutorial I was following: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-mod_security-with-apache-on-debian-ubuntu

Comment: Please run "apachectl configtest" and tell us the error message, if any.

Comment: It says "Action "apachectl configtest" failed. The Apache error log may have more information.

Comment: Well, did the apache error log have good information? And the test failure means there's a config error somewhere.

Comment: I reinstalled Mod_Security from this article. But when I try to test my server with a simple SQL injection, it doesn't show a 403 Forbidden page. http://blog.mattbrock.co.uk/hardening-the-security-on-ubuntu-server-14-04/